# Difference between assignment and replace

Tags: ruby, hash, replace

Given `a = {:a => 'a'}`, what's the difference between these two lines of code?

```
a = {:b => c}

a.replace({:b => c})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Hash#replace [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-replace)

```
a = {:a => 'a'}
```

The above line creates a Hash object and stores it in a variable `a`, `a` is a reference to an object

```
 a = {:a => 'a'}
 => {:a=>"a"}
 2.0.0p247 :040 > a.object_id
 => 70094303544580

a = {:b => c}
```

The above does the same thing the first line is doing, but it instead overriding the reference to the previous Hash object in memory

```
2.0.0p247 :042 > a = {:b => 'c'}
=> {:b=>"c"}
2.0.0p247 :043 > a.object_id
=> 70094303594480
```

See the `object_id` is different

Lastly:

```
2.0.0p247 :044 > a.replace({b: "d"})
=> {:b=>"d"}
2.0.0p247 :045 > a
=> {:b=>"d"}
2.0.0p247 :046 > a.object_id
=> 70094303594480
```

With replace we are referring to the same object previously referenced, but the content of the Hash Object is now altered, see the `object_id` remains same

Comment: `Object#object_id` is a good method to explain this post..So... +1 :)

Comment: I am amazed I got 2 down votes on this answer, and none of them commented why the need for the down vote

Answer (score 2):

This assigns a new object to the variable `a`:

```
a = {:b => c}
```

while this uses the existing hash and replaces/deletes the existing values:

```
a.replace({:b => c})
```

Answer (score 2):

Assignment does not do anything to the object that the variable has previously pointed to, but `replace` modifies the object.

If you had a piece of code pointing to `a`, then assignment of `a` to a different thing does not change that:

```
a = {:a => 'a'}
b = a
c = [:bar, a, :baz]

a = {:b => :foo}
b # => {:a => 'a'}
c # => [:bar, {:a => 'a'}, :baz]
```

but `replace` modifies whatever previously pointed to `a`:

```
a = {:a => 'a'}
b = a
c = [:bar, a, :baz]

a.replace({:b => :foo})
b # => {:b => :foo}
c # => [:bar, {:b => :foo}, :baz]
```